# Do the Zebra QL220 and QLn220 printers need to be set to different device languages?

Tags: windows-ce, zebra-printers, zpl, handheld, epl

My QLn220 printer is set to "hybrid_xml_zpl" and it works fine (I can send it CPCL commands, and it prints labels as I want them to look).

My QL220 printer (older model) is more quirky, though; it sometimes prints the raw commands I send it (untranslated) rather than viewing the commands as such. I don't know what device.languages is set to with that printer, because it has no usb port to attach to the PC (if it did, I could run Zebra Setup Utilities, sending it  "! U1 getvar "device.languages"" (which is what I did with the QLn220).

So my question is, should I set the QL220 (in code) to "hybrid_xml_zpl"? Or should I set it to "ZPL" or something else?

Apparently there are at least this many different options:

```
epl_zpl
EPL
hybrid_xml_zpl
ZPL
```

As I have not been able to read the Zebra belt printer's device language value programmatically (see [How can I read a string from OpenNETCF.IO.Ports.SerialPort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148634/how-can-i-read-a-string-from-opennetcf-io-ports-serialport)), I need to set it in code to *something* sensible.

What I'm afraid of is that it needs to be "hybrid_xml_zpl" for the QLn220, but something else (what?) for the QL220.

So: Will I need to have the user differentiate between printer models ( choose their model from a list), and then programmatically set the appropriate device language by sending that command to the printer, or can I get by with sending the same command/using the same device language (presumably "hybrid_xml_zpl") for both the QL220 *and* the QLn220?

If I need something other than "hybrid_xml_zpl" for the older QL220 models (perhaps this device language post-dates that model?), what *do* I need to set as the device language of the QL220?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the model of QL220 you have.  If its an A model, it cant run ZPL.  If its a B model, it can run either CPCL or ZPL but not at same time.  To be safe, can you program everything in CPCL mode since you are printing to legacy printers?

Comment: [You don't need signatures, taglines, or greetings in your posts.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: CPCL isn't one of the four options I saw; that is the language of the programs I'm sending it, though. We have abandoned the QL220 (don't know what, if any letter, is attached to it - the one I have sitting next to me doesn't have one). We are only supporting the QLn220 now.